# Is there a way to predict rendering times?

Tags: heuristics, graphics

In purpose of load balancing I need to approximatively predict rendering time my graphics software (in the specific case it's Autodesk Maya) needs to render a task given an input file (*.ma/*.mb) and rendering parameters.

1. An intuitive way to do it is to render several frames from different parts of a scene and to extrapolate the results. Is there a better way to do it?
2. If no, is it enough to render several separated frames or I should take short series of frames in different moments of the scene?

Comment: I would say in a perfect world you could, both of those way would work if you had enough data. Although due to your OS scheduling processes it will be different depending on what is happening on the computer. The rendering process could for example be preempted and ran later. Leading to slower results than expected.

Comment: Have you tried either?  How well do they work?  For 1., I'd expect that one issue is that if the frames you pick are not representative of the entire movie, your extrapolation might provide poor accuracy.  Also, as Spencer Wieczorek says, the running time when no other process is running is not a good predictor of the running time when other compute-intensive jobs are running, because of contention for resources (CPU, memory bandwidth, disk, cache, etc.)

Comment: @D.W. I haven't tried yet. It's a secondary aspect of my future thesis.
For a moment I think I should just try.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, here I'm lucky: it may happen that I will only have one rendering process per resource and no other load.

Comment: I don't think that this is a computer *science* question, at least not in its current form. You seem to be looking for advice in using a piece of software; that's what [SU] is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can predict it using Machine Larning / Data Mining algorithms, provided you have prior knowledge of the data. In your case,you should know the rendering time from previous experiments.

You can use any predition models. Some of them like bayesian models gives high accuracy prediction,but are computationally complex. Statistical models are very fast,but the provide less accurate results. You can use decision tree based models for a balanced performance.
CART algorithms is a good one. Use any datamining tools like weka,Rstudio or rapidminer to make the job easy.

Comment: I thought about it. But it's hard to formalize different types of textures and filters. Both don't represent limited set.

Comment: Sure, you *can* use ML algorithms for every problem, blindly. Never mind we don't even begin to have a stochastic model for what happens here, at all.